# "Integer too large" for a small compile time constant

Tags: java, integer

I have this:

```
switch (account){
    case 08120:
        // Savings deposit interest rate
        return null;                
    case 13100:
        // Receivables contractual interest
        return null;                
    case 16550:
       // Default management process accounts payable
       return null;                                
}
```

But the compiler complains tha the integer `08120` is too large!

What on earth is going on?

Comment: I've been staring at this for an hour. That error is not clear. And who uses octal anyway?

Comment: Why not use?One of the application is scientific calculator..Can be used extensively in mathematical softwares...similarly `0x` is hexadecimal

Comment: Hardly anyone uses octal any more. It makes no sense that a leading zero puts a number into octal. But we have all been stuck with it since C. Or possibly B.

Comment: Now I'm living up to my moniker. I'm convinced I've used leading zeros as initial guesses all over my code. Oops.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First things first: it's *unlikely* you've stumbled across a Java bug. Blame your code first.

`08120` is an *octal literal* in Java since it starts with a leading zero.

And 8 is not a valid octal digit (only 0 to 7 are).

Therefore you get a compilation error, albeit a little misleading.

Comment: There's no harm in having more than one answer. Perhaps yours was clearer.

Comment: Bathsheba's answer was 8 seconds earlier ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba Nah, you answered it perfectly fine - better than I did

Answer (score 2):

It's not a java bug.

You cannot use the format of **0XXXXX** for decimal numbers. Decimal numbers should be started with a non-zero digit.

Use **8120** instead of **08120**

Answer (score 1):

Numbers starting with a `0` are interpreted as an octal number also 8 would not fit in there since the valid octal digits can be 0 through to 7. This is not a bug, try starting your number without the `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little misleading/cryptic error message. In your code:

```
case 08120:
    // Savings deposit interest rate
    return null;
```

You have used `08120`, which is being interpreted as an **octal literal** instead of a **decimal** one. Since your next digit is `8` (not between `0 - 7`), it is an **invalid/out-of-range octal** literal and hence the compiler error.